# handler doesn't handle the event

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, event-handling, mousedown

I want to catch MouseDown events for all cells of the DataGrid object. I've specified a handler for it:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,119,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding Path=Text}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="CellMouseDown" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

But the event handler doesn't get called. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason may be that the event is handled inside the `DataGridCell`, so it does not reach your handler. You can try the [tunneling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) version of the event which is `PreviewMouseDown`.

Answer (score 1):

Your event is probably being handled by another handler while its going to your handler.

Here is an overview of **Routed events**

The 3 types of events are :

> **Bubbling**: Event handlers on the event source are invoked. The routed
>   event then routes to successive parent elements until reaching the
>   element tree root. Most routed events use the bubbling routing
>   strategy. Bubbling routed events are generally used to report input or
>   state changes from distinct controls or other UI elements.
>
> **Direct**: Only the source element itself is given the opportunity to
>   invoke handlers in response. This is analogous to the "routing" that
>   Windows Forms uses for events. However, unlike a standard CLR event,
>   direct routed events support class handling (class handling is
>   explained in an upcoming section) and can be used by EventSetter and
>   EventTrigger.
>
> **Tunneling**: Initially, event handlers at the element tree root are
>   invoked. The routed event then travels a route through successive
>   child elements along the route, towards the node element that is the
>   routed event source (the element that raised the routed event).
>   Tunneling routed events are often used or handled as part of the
>   compositing for a control, such that events from composite parts can
>   be deliberately suppressed or replaced by events that are specific to
>   the complete control. Input events provided in WPF often come
>   implemented as a tunneling/bubbling pair. Tunneling events are also
>   sometimes referred to as Preview events, because of a naming
>   convention that is used for the pairs.